# Failed in deploying .net core 3.1 app in App Service (via its Deployment Center)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

When deploying a .net core 3.1 app by using the Deployment Center (in App Service), I got the following 
failed error:

```
"error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1"
```

It was fine for me to deploy .net core 2.1 app in the environment. What should I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question. The SDK (.net core 3.1) is not deployed in App Service yet.

According to the following post, it should be there soon.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/129#issuecomment-569997549